# rails 4 image_tag is not linking to my digested image assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, assets, digest, precompiled

In rails 4 my image_tag("assets/logo.png") is not linking to the file with digest, the assets are precompiled also the images they are in public/assets/*

My production.rb:

```
Books::Application.configure do

  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
  config.assets.precompile += [/^[a-z0-9]\w+.(css|js)$/]

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

end
```

I spend 2 hours trying to resolve this totally out of options, ***why is this not working?***

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've just stumbled on this problem and the solution is pretty simple:
remove the "/assets" part of the input path.
Rails knows where to look at when using image_tag.
Be sure to place the image file in /assets/images.

Comment: Totally right, How could I overlook this using /assets/ in my image_path's since Rails 2 this seems to break it. ( Rails 4 no longer generates non digest assets by default. Probably my app has never been using digested image assets but I never noticed before!) Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Put your image in "assets/images".

In your view:

```
image_tag "my_image.png", class: "optional_class"
```

[API reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag)

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that you have not misspelled the name, if Rails can find the image in the asset folders, then it will link to the compiled asset path. If it **can not** find the image, it will link to the image folder instead

```
image_tag("logo.png") 
=> '/assets/logo-f2c87c4e3fda671a619ccb7...png'  # if image exists
=> '/images/logo.png'   # if image does not exists in asset folder
```